# The seller or the trader

Tags: characters, naming

I'm having difficulty choosing `the seller` or `the trader` when describing a character.

He is selling things at a flea market and I personally prefer `the seller`, the sound of it.

As English is not my first language I wonder if `the trader` would be more appropriate?

Comment: They have different implied meanings: A "seller" suggests someone who sells goods without a permanent address, like a fruit cart or farmer's market (as opposed to a *shopkeeper* with a brick-and-mortar address, or a *peddler* who walks door-to-door or lays wares on a sidewalk)…. A "trader" sounds archaic, (colonial or pre-industrial) where money was not common (fur trader) or crossing economic systems, like between currency and barter (hardware goods exchanged for seeds).

Comment: Thank you. I will use`the seller` as it's sounds better, fit the context better and I don't think `the trader` will fit in my story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I **personally** think the difference is between a "seller" and a "trader".

A seller sells goods for money. Such a person would almost certainly reject an offer to obtain goods in return for two chickens. Provide money (cash or credit) or go away.

A trader, on the other hand, would consider the offer and accept or reject it on the basis of whether someone else in the trader's circle of acquaintances might be willing, in turn, to trade something of value for the chickens.

The mind set of these two individuals is quite different.

A seller, in general, will focus on process to maximize the return on each transaction and to minimize the risks of operation. The seller seeks to minimize variability.

A trader, again in general, will focus on the ratio of risk and reward and will be willing to suspend adherence to process to gain an immediate gain. The trader accepts variability and often seeks to understand how that variability can be gamed to their advantage.

Only you can tell if this distinction is important to your story.

Comment: Thank you. I will use `the seller` as it's sounds better, fit the context better and I don't think `the trader` will fit in my story.

Comment: Please mark the question as an answer. It ties off the exchange and makes it more visible to others.